# HTML prompt() won't display

Tags: javascript

I have to create a program where you input a number 1-100 and it outputs the letter grade corresponding to your score and I'm having trouble getting the prompt to display. Here's some code:

```js
function myGrade() {
  var Input = prompt("Input grade here:");
  if (Input >= 90) {
    document.write("The score you entered is "
      Input ". Your letter grade is A.");
  } else if (Input >= 80 && Input < 90) {
    document.write("The score you entered is "
      Input ". Your letter grade is B.");
  } else if (Input >= 70 && Input < 80) {
    document.write("The score you entered is "
      Input ". Your letter grade is C.");
  } else if (Input >= 60 && Input < 70) {
    document.write("The score you entered is "
      Input ". Your letter grade is D.");
  } else if (Input < 60) {
    document.write("The score you entered is "
      Input ". Your letter grade is F.");
  }
}
```

I'm using `<body onload = "myGrade()">` above this snippet of code.

Comment: What errors did you see on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working : Copy this code into a file and load the file with a browser. The

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="">

<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  function myGrade() {    
    var Input = prompt("Input grade here:",50);
    if (Input >= 90) {
      document.write("The score you entered is "
       + Input  + ". Your letter grade is A.");
        } else if (Input >= 80 && Input < 90) {
      document.write("The score you entered is "
       + Input  + ". Your letter grade is B.");
    } else if (Input >= 70 && Input < 80) {
      document.write("The score you entered is "
      + Input  + ". Your letter grade is C.");
    } else if (Input >= 60 && Input < 70) {
      document.write("The score you entered is "
        + Input  + ". Your letter grade is D.");
    } else if (Input < 60) {
      document.write("The score you entered is "
        + Input  + ". Your letter grade is F.");
    }

  } </script>
</head>
<body onload = "myGrade()"> 
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What was the problem and what did you change?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install prompt first:

```
npm install prompt
```

So the solution is a little bit complicated than yours:

```
var prompt = require('prompt');

prompt.start();

prompt.get(['grade'], function (err, Input) {
      if (err) { return onErr(err); }
      if (Input.grade >= 90) {
          console.log("The score you entered is " +
            Input.grade  + ". Your letter grade is A.");
      } else if (Input.grade >= 80 && Input.grade < 90) {
          console.log("The score you entered is "
            + Input.grade + ". Your letter grade is B.");
      } else if (Input.grade >= 70 && Input.grade < 80) {
          console.log("The score you entered is "
           + Input.grade + ". Your letter grade is C.");
      } else if (Input.grade >= 60 && Input.grade < 70) {
          console.log("The score you entered is "
          +  Input.grade + ". Your letter grade is D.");
      } else if (Input.grade < 60) {
          console.log("The score you entered is "
           + Input.grade + ". Your letter grade is F.");
      }
});

function onErr(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return 1;
}
```

You can run the script with this command:

```
node script.js
```

[More information](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input).

Comment: `npm prompt` is something for prompting for input from the command line for node applications. This question was not tagged [tag:nodejs]. I think the OP is running his program in a browser.